# Assign a custom object id to a Membership User from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

i have this question about Membership Provider (MySQL) from .NET MVC 3.

I have a custom object called CustomObj with the structure:

- IdCustomObj
- Name

I want to Associate this CustomObj to any new MembershipUser that is created. Is this possible? If so, How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you do not specify if you want to store that data in your database or not, it's hard to answer exactly. Assuming you do want that, you'll need to create a MembershipUser and a MembershipProvider to handle your own MembershipUser which contains your name and object.

Since your object most likely itself contains a number of values, you must sort out how to store that in the database. A rather simple solution would be to serialize that object into json or xml when storing it, and deserialize it when your MembershipProvider gets your custom MembershipUser from the database again. There are many ways to do this and i'm sure you'll find yours.

So basically, inheriting the MySQL provider and overriding the various create and get user methods should get the job done. Note that you do not have to rewrite the entire MembershipProvider.

The nuts and bolts of it all can be found in the MSDN library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(v=VS.85).aspx (How to: Implement a Custom Membership User)

You can also read up on ScottGu's blog, where he provides source samples for providers: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/Source-Code-for-the-Built_2D00_in-ASP.NET-2.0-Providers-Now-Available-for-Download.aspx

However, you are probably better off getting the source for your specific provider to extend it.